# Client elements don't get updated when the form is posted back

Tags: asp.net, jquery, data-binding

I have a web form that contains lots of JavaScript functionalities to manipulate the DOM.
This is achieved using AJAX to call a service that will return me whatever I have to do, such as hiding elements, cascading drop downs, removing and inserting new items to a select, etc.

Everything works as expected apart from one particular function. This function only disables and sets a default value in a select element depending on what my AJAX call returned. For instance, let's say I had selected "foo" from the following select and saved the record:

```
<select id="mySelect2">
  <option value="0">Default</option>
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="another_foo">Foo 2</option>
</select>
```

Great! Now I have changed other element in my web form that triggered off my AJAX call. The returned data tells me that I should select Default and disable the select element. This works just fine. But, when I save the record again and verify it in the DB the Default value of 0 in this case is not being saved. The record remains with the previous selected item ("foo").

If you are curious, I using the following code to accomplish this:

1. Binds the AJAX call

   ```
   $('myElement').change(GetData);
   ```
2. GetData method

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'myUrl',
       data: "{'id':'" + myIdFromMyElement + "'"}",
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: OnSuccess,
       error: OnError
   });
   ```
3. Manipulate the select element according to the returned data:

   ```
   function OnSuccess(data, textStatus) { 
       if (data.d.DisableMySelect2){
           $('#mySelect2').val('0');
           $('#mySelect2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       }
   }
   ```

Why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

Further investigations shown that my web form does not unbind the changed value correctly but when I go `Request.Form["mySelect2"]` I can actually see the updated value, so apparently there is nothing wrong with the client side of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is happening because the form elements that are [disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1) aren't submitted with the form.

You may want to handle form submission trough an AJAX call or use a hidden input to store the value of the selected option of the disabled SELECT element.

Comment: yep apparently you are right but further investigations shown that my web form does not unbind the value correctly but my request contains the updated value when you go Request.Form .... ?!